# add a custom field in customer account just visible in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-field

I want to add a text box in the customer information
This text box appears only in admin, just visible in admin area
I would like information about each customer is stored in the TextBox

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

create new module add

```
<resources>
      <customerattribute_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>SilkSoftware_ModuleName</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_setup>
      <customerattribute_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_write>
      <customerattribute_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_read>
</resources>
```

add below code in //sql/customerattribute_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "custom_field",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Custom Field",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "custom_field");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 0)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```